# How to intersect dataframe without added columns?

Tags: python, pandas, merge, concatenation, intersection

I am trying to do a simple intersection of dataframes, but no matter the method (`pd.merge` or `pd.concat`) I always endup with duplicated columns.

Say the two dataframes are:

```py
df1 = pd.DataFrame(
    data = np.stack([
        np.arange(4),
        np.random.rand(4),
        np.random.rand(4),
    ],axis=-1),
    columns = ["A","B","C"]
)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(
    data = np.stack([
        np.arange(4)+2,
        np.random.rand(4),
        np.random.rand(4),
    ],axis=-1),
    columns = ["A","B","C"]
)

df1,df2
```

```
(     A         B         C
 0  0.0  0.165849  0.516438
 1  1.0  0.116661  0.395433
 2  2.0  0.758229  0.386642
 3  3.0  0.057719  0.802317,
      A         B         C
 0  2.0  0.899924  0.545800
 1  3.0  0.792242  0.187410
 2  4.0  0.332168  0.778160
 3  5.0  0.164429  0.509884)
```

The result I want to achieve is this:

```
    Source     A         B         C 
 2  df1        2.0  0.758229  0.386642
 3  df1        3.0  0.057719  0.802317
 0  df2        2.0  0.899924  0.545800
 1  df2        3.0  0.792242  0.187410
```

I tried with pd.concat, but I have duplicated columns:

```py
# Try with pd.concat inner
for df in [df1,df2]:
    df.set_index("A",inplace=True)

df = pd.concat([df1,df2],join="inner",axis=1).reset_index()
df
```

```
    A   B   C   B   C
0   2.0 0.758229    0.386642    0.899924    0.54580
1   3.0 0.057719    0.802317    0.792242    0.18741
```

And pd.merges also gives duplicated columns:

```py
df = pd.merge(
    left = df1,
    right = df2,
    how="inner",
    on = "A"
)
df
```

```
    A   B_x C_x B_y C_y
0   2.0 0.758229    0.386642    0.899924    0.54580
1   3.0 0.057719    0.802317    0.792242    0.18741
```

Anyone has a clean way to do this in pandas ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`isin`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.isin.html) and then `concat`:

```
pd.concat([df1[df1.A.isin(df2.A)].assign(source='df1'),
           df2[df2.A.isin(df1.A)].assign(source='df2')])
```

Example:

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'A': [0,1,2,3], 'B': [1,2,3,4], 'C': [5,6,7,8]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'A': [2,3,4,5], 'B': [11,12,13,14], 'C': [15,16,17,18]})
pd.concat([df1[df1.A.isin(df2.A)].assign(source='df1'), df2[df2.A.isin(df1.A)].assign(source='df2')])
```

Result:

```
   A   B   C source
2  2   3   7    df1
3  3   4   8    df1
0  2  11  15    df2
1  3  12  16    df2
```

Comment: Thank you, it works. However I would need something general so I can use it for n >> 1 dataframes.

Comment: for n > 2 dataframes you can first get the intersecting values of columns `A` of all dataframes in a loop using python `set` operations or numpy `intersect1d` and then concat the dataframes sliced with this intersection.